# Testing whether two Eigen decompositions are equal

Tags: pca

I have an eigen decomposition of a 30 variable covariance matrix calculated using 5y of daily data and would like to compare it to a different 5y period to see if the eigenvalues are the same. Obviously they will not be exactly the same due to noise in the signal but can I test statistically that they are the the same?

"An asymptotic chi-square test for the equality of two correlation matrices" by R. Jennrich

The closest match I have found is a paper to test the equivalence on two correlation matrices, but as I am working in the Eigenvector space I would prefer a test that is performed on the eigenvectors (plus the paper is quite old).

Also on a similar topic what is the minimum length of time I can run a PCA analysis over for 30 variables on daily data. Clearly if i can generate more eigenvector decompositions to compare I can be more confident in my results.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want to test equality of *eigenvalues* (as stated in the first sentence), *eigenvectors* (as in the penultimate paragraph), or the full *"eigendecomposition"* (as in the title)?  (The latter would be equivalent to testing equality of the correlation matrices.)

Comment: Sorry I do mean test the full eigen-decomposition, however not that you mention it, being able to test the eigenvectors seperately would be nice so I can try to understand where any differences are coming from.